# Non-Alpine dind docker image

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

Is there an existing non-Alpine dind docker image?

Bind-mounting the host's docker socket does not work for me.  I need proper dind.  Docker's dind images seem to be all Alpine based, which also doesn't work for me.

Comment: Yes, they exist. You can search Docker Hub for them. Or you can take the official image and fork it from github.

Comment: Why do you think that the problem is in Alpine and not Docker?

Comment: @JakubJirutka Not sure what you mean, but Alpine Linux, for instance, won't run OpenJDK 12, and there is no Alpine JDK 12 yet.

Comment: I'm assuming you're trying to run a Java build inside the Docker image, and want to spin up other images as part of the build (test-containers)?

I was able to get it to work with the openjdk-11 Docker image by mounting the docker sock as suggested by Nilesh. I just added:
-v "/var/run/docker.sock":"/var/run/docker.sock"

To my Docker command

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly an answer to your question, but might solve your needs:

I assume that you don't really need non-Alpine, but rather GLIBC-enabled image.

I wanted an Docker-in-Docker capable image for Gitlab CI, which would have OpenJDK 12.
Such image is not yet available - AdoptOpenJDK images do not have DinD, and the official `docker:*` images can't install normal OpenJDK.

So I combined `adoptopenjdk:12` with `docker:stable`, and it seems to work.

```
docker build --label docker-with-openjdk12 .
```

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#               NOTE: THIS DOCKERFILE IS GENERATED VIA "update.sh"
#
#                       PLEASE DO NOT EDIT IT DIRECTLY.
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#      https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
#

FROM docker:stable

ENV LANG='en_US.UTF-8' LANGUAGE='en_US:en' LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8'

RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps curl binutils \
    && GLIBC_VER="2.29-r0" \
    && ALPINE_GLIBC_REPO="https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download" \
    && GCC_LIBS_URL="https://archive.archlinux.org/packages/g/gcc-libs/gcc-libs-9.1.0-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz" \
    && GCC_LIBS_SHA256="91dba90f3c20d32fcf7f1dbe91523653018aa0b8d2230b00f822f6722804cf08" \
    && ZLIB_URL="https://archive.archlinux.org/packages/z/zlib/zlib-1%3A1.2.11-3-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz" \
    && ZLIB_SHA256=17aede0b9f8baa789c5aa3f358fbf8c68a5f1228c5e6cba1a5dd34102ef4d4e5 \
    && curl -LfsS https://alpine-pkgs.sgerrand.com/sgerrand.rsa.pub -o /etc/apk/keys/sgerrand.rsa.pub \
    && SGERRAND_RSA_SHA256="823b54589c93b02497f1ba4dc622eaef9c813e6b0f0ebbb2f771e32adf9f4ef2" \
    && echo "${SGERRAND_RSA_SHA256} */etc/apk/keys/sgerrand.rsa.pub" | sha256sum -c - \
    && curl -LfsS ${ALPINE_GLIBC_REPO}/${GLIBC_VER}/glibc-${GLIBC_VER}.apk > /tmp/glibc-${GLIBC_VER}.apk \
    && apk add /tmp/glibc-${GLIBC_VER}.apk \
    && curl -LfsS ${ALPINE_GLIBC_REPO}/${GLIBC_VER}/glibc-bin-${GLIBC_VER}.apk > /tmp/glibc-bin-${GLIBC_VER}.apk \
    && apk add /tmp/glibc-bin-${GLIBC_VER}.apk \
    && curl -Ls ${ALPINE_GLIBC_REPO}/${GLIBC_VER}/glibc-i18n-${GLIBC_VER}.apk > /tmp/glibc-i18n-${GLIBC_VER}.apk \
    && apk add /tmp/glibc-i18n-${GLIBC_VER}.apk \
    && /usr/glibc-compat/bin/localedef --force --inputfile POSIX --charmap UTF-8 "$LANG" || true \
    && echo "export LANG=$LANG" > /etc/profile.d/locale.sh \
    && curl -LfsS ${GCC_LIBS_URL} -o /tmp/gcc-libs.tar.xz \
    && echo "${GCC_LIBS_SHA256} */tmp/gcc-libs.tar.xz" | sha256sum -c - \
    && mkdir /tmp/gcc \
    && tar -xf /tmp/gcc-libs.tar.xz -C /tmp/gcc \
    && mv /tmp/gcc/usr/lib/libgcc* /tmp/gcc/usr/lib/libstdc++* /usr/glibc-compat/lib \
    && strip /usr/glibc-compat/lib/libgcc_s.so.* /usr/glibc-compat/lib/libstdc++.so* \
    && curl -LfsS ${ZLIB_URL} -o /tmp/libz.tar.xz \
    && echo "${ZLIB_SHA256} */tmp/libz.tar.xz" | sha256sum -c - \
    && mkdir /tmp/libz \
    && tar -xf /tmp/libz.tar.xz -C /tmp/libz \
    && mv /tmp/libz/usr/lib/libz.so* /usr/glibc-compat/lib \
    && apk del --purge .build-deps glibc-i18n \
    && rm -rf /tmp/*.apk /tmp/gcc /tmp/gcc-libs.tar.xz /tmp/libz /tmp/libz.tar.xz /var/cache/apk/*

ENV JAVA_VERSION jdk-12.0.2+10

RUN set -eux; \
    apk add --virtual .fetch-deps curl; \
    ARCH="$(apk --print-arch)"; \
    case "${ARCH}" in \
       aarch64|arm64) \
         ESUM='855f046afc5a5230ad6da45a5c811194267acd1748f16b648bfe5710703fe8c6'; \
         BINARY_URL='https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk12-binaries/releases/download/jdk-12.0.2%2B10/OpenJDK12U-jdk_aarch64_linux_hotspot_12.0.2_10.tar.gz'; \
         ;; \
       armhf) \
         ESUM='9fec85826ffb7b2b2cf2853a6ed3e001b528ed5cf13e435cd13026398b5178d8'; \
         BINARY_URL='https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk12-binaries/releases/download/jdk-12.0.2%2B10/OpenJDK12U-jdk_arm_linux_hotspot_12.0.2_10.tar.gz'; \
         ;; \
       ppc64el|ppc64le) \
         ESUM='4b0c9f5cdea1b26d7f079fa6478aceebf1923c947c4209d5709c0869dd71b98f'; \
         BINARY_URL='https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk12-binaries/releases/download/jdk-12.0.2%2B10/OpenJDK12U-jdk_ppc64le_linux_hotspot_12.0.2_10.tar.gz'; \
         ;; \
       s390x) \
         ESUM='9897deeaf7a2c90374fbaca8b3eb8e63267d8fc1863b43b21c0bfc86e4783470'; \
         BINARY_URL='https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk12-binaries/releases/download/jdk-12.0.2%2B10/OpenJDK12U-jdk_s390x_linux_hotspot_12.0.2_10.tar.gz'; \
         ;; \
       amd64|x86_64) \
         ESUM='1202f536984c28d68681d51207a84b6c76e5998579132d3fe1b8085aa6a5f21e'; \
         BINARY_URL='https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk12-binaries/releases/download/jdk-12.0.2%2B10/OpenJDK12U-jdk_x64_linux_hotspot_12.0.2_10.tar.gz'; \
         ;; \
       *) \
         echo "Unsupported arch: ${ARCH}"; \
         exit 1; \
         ;; \
    esac; \
    curl -LfsSo /tmp/openjdk.tar.gz ${BINARY_URL}; \
    echo "${ESUM} */tmp/openjdk.tar.gz" | sha256sum -c -; \
    mkdir -p /opt/java/openjdk; \
    cd /opt/java/openjdk; \
    tar -xf /tmp/openjdk.tar.gz --strip-components=1; \
    apk del --purge .fetch-deps; \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*; \
    rm -rf /tmp/openjdk.tar.gz;

ENV JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/openjdk \
    PATH="/opt/java/openjdk/bin:$PATH"
CMD ["jshell"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You just want to run Docker to perform CI System (build, run, push container images to hub) in Jenkins. Jenkins Master will launch Jenkins Slave as container and it will perform CI operation in it.

**Yes you can run docker commands in inside jenkins slave container.**

We required Docker binaries files in jenkins slave container, here while creating docker image through docker file we have added docker binaries file to it.

Once image build, we have just to volume mount Docker sock `/var/run/docker.sock` of host machine on container `/var/run/docker.sock`.

Here we are executing Docker-daemon from host machine and Docker client as jenkins slave container.

Please refer below GIT and Docker Hub repo:

- https://github.com/Nilesh7756/dind-jnlp-slave.git
- https://hub.docker.com/r/nilesh7756/jnlp-slave/

Comment: Very clever! This solved it for me with the openjdk11 image. I needed to run test-containers as part of the CI build, which itself was running the openjdk-11 image. I added

`-v "/var/run/docker.sock":"/var/run/docker.sock" \`

 to my docker command, and it was able to run images using the host's daemon.

Thanks!